# Can joining with an iTVF be as fast as joining with a temp table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> #### Scenario
>
> Quick background on this one: I am attempting to optimize the use of an inline table-valued function `uf_GetVisibleCustomers(@cUserId)`. The iTVF wraps a view `CustomerView` and filters out all rows containing data for customers whom the provided requesting user is not permitted to see. This way, should selection criteria ever change in the future for certain user types, we won't have to implement that new condition a hundred times (hyperbole) all over the SQL codebase.
>
> Performance is not great, however, so I want to fix that before encouraging use of the iTVF. Changed database object names here just so it's easier to demonstrate (hopefully).

### Queries

In attempting to optimize our iTVF `uf_GetVisibleCustomers`, I've noticed that the following SQL …

```
CREATE TABLE #tC ( idCustomer INT )

INSERT #tC
SELECT idCustomer
FROM [dbo].[uf_GetVisibleCustomers]('requester')

SELECT T.fAmount
FROM [Transactions] T
JOIN #tC C ON C.idCustomer = T.idCustomer
```

… is orders of magnitude faster than my original (IMO more readable, likely to be used) SQL here…

```
SELECT T.fAmount
FROM [Transactions] T
JOIN [dbo].[uf_GetVisibleCustomers]('requester') C ON C.idCustomer = T.idCustomer
```

I don't get why this is. The former (top block of SQL) returns ~700k rows in 17 seconds on a fairly modest development server. The latter (second block of SQL) returns the same number of rows in about ten minutes when there is no other user activity on the server. Maybe worth noting that there is a WHERE clause, however I have omitted it here for simplicity; it is the same for both queries.

### Execution Plan

Below is the execution plan for the first. It enjoys automatic parallelism as mentioned while the latter query isn't worth displaying here because it's just massive (expands the entire iTVF and underlying view, subqueries). Anyway, the latter also does not execute in parallel (AFAIK) to any extent.

[image: Screenshot of live execution plan in SSMS]

### My Questions

1. Is it possible to achieve performance comparable to the first block without a temp table?

   - That is, with the relative simplicity and human-readability of the slower SQL.
2. Why is a join to a temp table faster than a join to iTVF?
3. Why is it faster to use a temp table than an in-memory table populated the same way?

Beyond those explicit questions, if someone can point me in the right direction toward understanding this better in general then I would be very grateful.

Comment: depends somewhat on your sql server version, but temp tables on average get better stats than the estimate of a single row from TVF...

Comment: I think the issue is not with "in-memory table" - it executes just as fast as a temp table. The issue is with the user-defined functions - they are executed row by row, which is much slower than standard SQL set operations. I would use iTVF only if there is no other option for the task. Readability of your SQL code is a subjective thing - you can greatly improve it by using more meaningful/intuitive names (i.e., "#tC"? - I bet there is a better name for this table :)

Comment: it might help to poste your function's code...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the DDL for your inline function - it's hard to say what the issue is. It would also help to see the actual execution plans for both queries (perhaps you could try: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). That said, I can offer some food for thought.

As you mentioned, the iTVF accesses the underlying tables, views and associated indexes. If your statistics are not up-to-date you can get a bad plan, that won't happen with your temp table. On that note, too, how long does it take to populate that temp table?

Another thing to look at (again, this is why DDL is helpful) is: are the data type's the same for Transactions.idCustomer and #TC.idCustomer? I see a hash match in the plan you posted which seems bad for a join between two IDs (a nested loops or merge join would be better). This could be slowing both queries down but would appear to have a more dramatic impact on the query that leverages your iTVF.

Again this ^^^ is speculation based on my experience. A couple quick things to try (not as a perm fix but for troubleshooting):
1. Check to see if re-compiling your query when using the iTVF speeds things up (this would be a sign of a bad stats or a bad execution plan being cached and re-used)
2. Try forcing a parallel plan for the iTVF query. You can do this by adding OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649) to the end of your query of by using make_parallel() by Adam Machanic.